# Connection reset error trying to reach Docker Express API Endpoint on Windows 10

Tags: docker, express

I'm running Docker For Windows on Windows 10. I'm new to Docker and created an Express/Mongo API service following [this tutorial](https://hackernoon.com/build-a-crud-api-with-mongodb-express-and-docker-70510c6f706b).

I start the image with the following command: 
`docker-compose -f docker/docker-compose.yml up -d`

The container spins up without error. However, when attempt to hit the API I just get 'connection reset' messages. I've tried the following:

- `curl http://localhost:80`
- `curl http://localhost:80/api/documents`
- `curl http://127.0.0.1:80`
- `curl http://127.0.0.1:80/api/documents`

I tried starting an image of `nginx` and running on port 80 and hitting it with `curl http://localhost:80` and that worked.

### docker.compose.yml file

```
version: '3'
services:
  backend:
    build: 
      context: ../
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile.production 
      args:
        port: ${PORT}
    env_file:
      - ../.env
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "${PORT}:${PORT}"
    environment:
      WAIT_HOSTS: database:27017
  database:
    image: mongo:4.0
    env_file:
      - ../.env
    expose:
      - 27017
    command: "mongod --smallfiles --logpath=${MONGO_LOG_FILE}"
```

### dockerfile

```
FROM node:10.12.0-alpine
ADD https://github.com/ufoscout/docker-compose-wait/releases/download/2.2.1/wait /wait
RUN chmod +x /wait
WORKDIR /home/nodejs/app
ENV NODE_ENV prod
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install --only=production
ARG port=80
EXPOSE $port
COPY . ./
CMD /wait && node index.js
```

### index.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

const dbName = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'dev' ? 'database-test' : 'database';
const url = `mongodb://${process.env.MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME}:${process.env.MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD}@${dbName}:27017?authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1&authSource=admin`;
const options = {
  useNewUrlParser: true, 
  reconnectTries: 60, 
  reconnectInterval: 1000
}

const routes = require('./routes/routes.js');
const port = process.env.PORT || 80;
const app = express();
const http = require('http').Server(app);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use('/api', routes);
app.use((req, res) => {
  res.status(404);
})

MongoClient.connect(url, options, (err, database) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(`FATAL MONGODB CONNECTION ERROR: ${err}:${err.stack}`);
    process.exit(1);
  }
  app.locals.db = database.db('api');
  http.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Listening on port " + port);
    app.emit('APP_STARTED');
  })
})

module.exports = app;
```

Any help and suggestions for things to try would be appreciated.

---

**Update**
If I spin up the mongodb separately using `docker run -d -p 27017:27017 mongo` and then run my express app with `node index.js`, everything seems to work fine. The way I'm using the docker-compose seems to be the issue here. It seems that the backend image keeps restarting over and over again when I look at the images via `docker ps`

Comment: What is the CMD line with the && supposed to do? Besides it is a good idea to have separate containers for different services.

Comment: @eckes, according to the linked tutorial, that line will call the referenced utility that will wait for dependent services to have been spun up (in this case, mongo) and then starts the express service. Not sure what you mean by your second comment since the each service has a separate container here (one for express API and one for the db)

Comment: Ah I see, `/wait` is a script. Does the container log anything interesting, especially the wait script, does it know which port to contact and does it succeed in time?

Comment: @eckes - When you say log anything, do you mean from when I run docker logs [container] or is there another place I could check? As I mentioned, I'm still pretty new, so I'm flying a little blind in terms of not even knowing where to go to see debug info. I'll post the log info later when I have a chance.

Comment: Well, no idea where your specific containers and software logs, but if it is well behaved the error why the service terminates (and is restarted) should show up in `docker log` yes. It is the stdout of the wait script and the node process.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the very same issue by switching the node.js image from `alpine` to `slim`. I debugged the similar problem you've described and it seems that mongodb received the request and the client was breaking connection when mongo responded. The solution is a workaround, but I hope it helps someone.

Update:
I've searched a bit and found out the potential issue: https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/docker-nodejs-alpine-distro-csfle-mongodb-enterprise-cryptd/6123/4